# How to display a value in a PyQt text field using matplotlib's object picking function?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, qtgui

I am using PyQt 4 for a basic GUI and matplotlib for a plot from which I want to read the coordinates of the plotted data points. Based on [these examples](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) (simple picking example), I have the simple problem that I cannot display the coordinates of a data point in a text field such as QtGui.QLabel(). I do not understand why I cannot call the instance `Window.msg` in the method `onpick()`. Probably it is because the instance it not given to the method. I only have a basic understanding of object oriented programming (but I am working on it), so the problem is my lack of knowledge.

My question: How to display the coordinates of chosen data (by clicking on it) from a matplotlib plot in my GUI based on PyQT (in that case in my label `lbl`)?

Also, it would be nice to highlight the chosen data point in the plot.

Here is my code (working):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QTAgg as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class Window(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):  
       self.msg = '0'

       # a figure instance to plot on
       self.figure = plt.figure()
       self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
       self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)

       # a label
       self.lbl = QtGui.QLabel(self.msg)

       # set the layout
       layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
       layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
       layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
       layout.addWidget(self.lbl)
       self.setLayout(layout)

       self.plot()

    def plot(self):
        # random data
        data = [np.random.random() for i in range(10)]
        # create an axis
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        # discards the old graph
        ax.hold(False)
        # plot data
        line, = ax.plot(data, 'o', picker=5)  # 5 points tolerance
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event',  Window.onpick)

    def onpick(self):
        thisline = self.artist
        xdata = thisline.get_xdata()
        ydata = thisline.get_ydata()
        ind = self.ind

        # show data
        self.msg = (xdata[ind], ydata[ind])
        print(self.msg)

        # This does not work:
        #Window.lbl.setText(self.msg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Window()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The self is being overlapped by the picker (not sure why). In any case this should work:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QTAgg as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Window(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):  
       self.msg = '0'

       # a figure instance to plot on
       self.figure = plt.figure()
       self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
       self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)

       # a label
       self.lbl = QtGui.QLabel(self.msg)

       # set the layout
       layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
       layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
       layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
       layout.addWidget(self.lbl)
       self.setLayout(layout)

       self.plot()

    def changelabel(arg):
        main.lbl.setText(str(arg[0])+' '+str(arg[1]))

    def plot(self):
        # random data
        data = [np.random.random() for i in range(10)]
        # create an axis
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        # discards the old graph
        ax.hold(False)
        # plot data
        line, = ax.plot(data, 'o', picker=5)  # 5 points tolerance
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event',  Window.onpick)

    def onpick(self):
        thisline = self.artist
        xdata = thisline.get_xdata()
        ydata = thisline.get_ydata()
        ind = self.ind

        # show data
        self.msg = (xdata[ind], ydata[ind])
        print(self.msg)
#        Window.changelabel(self.msg)
        main.lbl.setText(str(self.msg[0])+' '+str(self.msg[1]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Window()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

, the change is in the `setText` function, since I call it directly from the variable (no `self` or `Window`).

```
main.lbl.setText(str(self.msg[0])+' '+str(self.msg[1]))
```